# Join Calculated Value to String

Tags: less

I have the following less code:

```
li {
  @count: 6;
  &:nth-child(~"{@count}n") { 
  }
}
```

I would like this result in:

```
li {
  &:nth-child(6n) { 
  }
}
```

But I get the error "ParseError: Unrecognised input".

How can I make this work?

Thank You,
Miguel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
li {
    @count: 6;
    &:nth-child(@{count}n) {
        // ...
    }
}
```